# How to add a list of product in a view?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo-9

i'm using odoo 8 and i want to know how to add a page that contains list of product and theire quantity in a view,  to mention in a request for intervention which products we are going to modify. In that way we can estimate how costs every intervention

view.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_intervention_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">cmms.intervention.form</field>
        <field name="model">cmms.intervention</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Intervention request" version="7.0">
                <header>
                    <button name="action_broadcast"  type="object" string="Déffuser mail" icon="STOCK_REDO"/>
                    <button name="action_done" states="draft" string="Valider" type="object" icon="gtk-apply"/>
                    <button name="action_cancel" states="done," string="Annuler" type="object"  icon="gtk-cancel"/>
                    <button name="action_draft" states="cancel" string="Remettre en brouillon" type="object" icon="terp-stock_effects-object-colorize"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" />
                </header>
                <sheet>
                <group>
                <group>
                <field name="name" select="1" />
                <field name="user_id" select="1" colspan="1" />
                <field name="user2_id"  />
                <field name="priority"  />
                <field name="state_machine" />
                 <field name="product_id"/>
                </group>
                <group>
                <field name="type" select="1" colspan="1" />
                <field name="equipment_id" select="1" colspan="1" />
                <field name="date_inter"  />
                <field name="date_end"  />
                </group>
                </group>
                <newline />
                <notebook colspan="1">
                    <page string="Motif d'intervention">
                        <field name="motif" />
                    </page>
                    <page string="Observation">
                        <field name="observation" />
                    </page>
                     </notebook>

                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
     </data>
   </openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a field One2many to the page and then define the tree view, somethnig like:

```
<field name="fieldOne2many">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <field name="product_id"/>
        <field name="quantity"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

But first, you must define it in models.py and create the class related to the one2many, that contains *quantity* and *product_id*.

Regards.